# How to subtract a number from itself multiple times?

Tags: ruby, math, subtraction

I am trying to get user input for a number then a second number that tells the program how many times to do some basic math. I got the addition to work and the multiplication, but I am not sure how to get the subtraction to subtract a number from itself by the user selected number of times.

```
print "Please Enter a numeric value: ";  # get the first input from user

input1 = STDIN.gets.chomp!.to_i

puts ("\n" * 2)                           #Scroll the screen 3 times

print "Enter total number of times a value needs to be computed from #{input1} "; 

input2 = STDIN.gets.chomp!.to_i

puts ("\n" * 2) 

print "Addition : ", (input1.to_i * input2.to_i), "\n";       
print "Subtraction : " , (input1.to_i - input2.to_i), "\n";     
print "Multiplication : " , (input1.to_i ** input2.to_i), "\n";
```

Comment: I had misunderstood the question, so deleted my answer. I think you misunderstood `[v]*n`, however, where `v` is the first number and `n` is the second.  This is not multiplication.  `[2]*2 => [2,2]`, so the subtraction operation would have resulted in `2-2 => 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
print "Subtraction : " , input1.to_i-(input1.to_i*input2.to_i), "\n";
```

Comment: Ha! So simple! you are a genius! Thanks Sergio, that works perfectly!

Comment: hmm, well after further testing, it does not correctly subtract, so if I input first 2 and 2 second it should return 0, but it come back with -4 since it multiplies then subtracts the results, I need 2-2 or say 5-5-5 = -5

Comment: yep that got it, now i see a flaw in my addition, if I input 21 first and 1 second it gives me 21 back since I am cheating and using multiplication. I will mark accepted since you answered my intial question. Thanks much!

Comment: @user3295198 I'm afraid that this soln does not work for negative numbers for example (-5) and I've given a better ruby way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **Ruby way**

```
print "Subtraction : " , Array.new(input2,input1).inject(:-), "\n";
```

**Ex:**

```
1.9.3p448 :058 > Array.new(3,-5)
 => [-5, -5, -5] 
1.9.3p448 :059 > Array.new(3,-5).inject(:-)
 => 5 
1.9.3p448 :060 > 
1.9.3p448 :061 >   Array.new(3,5)
 => [5, 5, 5] 
1.9.3p448 :062 > Array.new(3,5).inject(:+)
 => 15 
1.9.3p448 :063 >
```